# Create automatically a certain numbers of Entrys - Tkinter/Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to use Tkinter to write a code where the user can enter a number N. Depending on this number N the program automatically (i dont want to use any buttons) creates N-Entry rows.

My solution works partially:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
Label(root, text = "Enter Number of columns").grid(row = 0, column = 0)

N = IntVar()
e_N = Entry(root, textvariable = N).grid(row = 0, column = 1)


# Put trace callbacks on the Entry IntVar
def create_rows(name, index, mode):
    rows = N.get()
    for i in range(rows):
        Entry(root).grid(row = i + 1, column = 0)

N.trace('w', create_rows)

# Setting the vars will trigger the trace
N.set(2)

mainloop()
```

When you run the code for the first time, it works fine. If you delete the number two and enter a new number, new lines are automatically created. However, an error message is displayed :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 508, in get
    return self._tk.getint(value)
_tkinter.TclError: expected integer but got ""

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-97-2da00b5c0b50>", line 12, in create_rows
    rows = N.get()
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 510, in get
    return int(self._tk.getdouble(value))
_tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got ""
```

This error is repeated as soon as the old number is deleted and a new one is entered.

Does someone know what is wrong and how to fix it?

Also as an extra: Only new lines can be created, i.e. if you first enter 5 and then 3, the last two lines are not deleted.

***Edited code:***

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
Label(root, text = "Enter Number of columns").grid(row = 0, column = 0)

N = IntVar()
e_N = Entry(root, textvariable = N).grid(row = 0, column = 1)


# Put trace callbacks on the Entry IntVar
def create_rows(name, index, mode):
    try:
        rows = N.get()
    except _tkinter.TclError:
        ""
    for i in range(rows):
        Entry(root).grid(row = i + 1, column = 0)

N.trace('w', create_rows)

# Setting the vars will trigger the trace
N.set(2)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Why not use a `Text` widget? That allows you to input multiple lines of text.

Comment: Suggest to use `Spinbox` instead of `Entry`, then you don't need to cater the exception.

Comment: Add `rows = 0` before `try:`

Answer (score 0):

Putting a trace on the value of `N` means it calls `create_rows` whenever it changes, including just after you deleted the original number, but before you type the new one. You could put `N.get()` inside a `try`/`except`, and only add new lines if the contents of the number entry are a valid integer. This will handle the deleted case when the value is an empty string, and also if someone types a non-number into the entry.

Comment: I used your tip. But unfortunately it still doesn't work. I never used try/except before, so i probably messed somewhere up.  Could u pls check my edited code.